# CSS - Scrollable horizontal div with two row and infinite width?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to do an infinite and horizontal div (row) containing images like this : 
And scroll x to slide and see the other image hidden by overflow ..

see this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nbjx50ge/
I would like to have the 9 first items in a single row but with overflow-x

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="row-1">
                    <img id="emoji-glace" src="img/emoji/Glace.png">
                    <img id="emoji-cafe" src="img/emoji/Cafe.png">
                    <img id="emoji-biere" src="img/emoji/Biere.png">
                    <img id="emoji-repas" src="img/emoji/Repas.png">
                    <img id="emoji-sushi" src="img/emoji/Sushi.png">
                    <img id="emoji-pizza" src="img/emoji/Pizza.png">
                    <img id="emoji-repas" src="img/emoji/Repas.png">
                    <img id="emoji-sushi" src="img/emoji/Sushi.png">
                    <img id="emoji-pizza" src="img/emoji/Pizza.png">
            </div>
            <div id="row-2">
                    <img id="emoji-glace" src="img/emoji/Glace.png">
                    <img id="emoji-cafe" src="img/emoji/Cafe.png">
                    <img id="emoji-biere" src="img/emoji/Biere.png">
                    <img id="emoji-repas" src="img/emoji/Repas.png">
                    <img id="emoji-sushi" src="img/emoji/Sushi.png">
                    <img id="emoji-pizza" src="img/emoji/Pizza.png">
                    <img id="emoji-repas" src="img/emoji/Repas.png">
                    <img id="emoji-sushi" src="img/emoji/Sushi.png">
                    <img id="emoji-pizza" src="img/emoji/Pizza.png">
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `white-space: nowrap` on rows.

```css
#container {
  width: 30%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#container > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#emoji {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="row-1">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="row-2">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
    <img id="emoji" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/06/12/28600CB500000578-3070135-image-a-30_1430912161865.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```